# How to calculate statistics on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at random pages and random people to see how people got voted on in questions.

What I was looking to see was the average number of upvotes (no downvoted question), the median etc.

But then I wanted to look at how questions got upvoted in say the past 2 years compared to 2010-2011.  I looked at random people but the results vary too much to see any real data. Is it possible to access this data of Stack Overflow, or do you have to be a moderator?

Comment: See http://data.stackexchange.com/ - you can write queries to extract the relevant data, and run them on a weekly dump of the site content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create custom queries in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, also called [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) which comes with an excellent [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) that learns you both how to use the tool and how to query with SQL statements.

To get you started I created this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414382#graph) that you can fork to experiment on your own. I take here voting over the years for the c# and java tags.

```sql
select year(v.creationdate)
     , count(*) as total
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 2 then 1
           else 0
           end ) as upvotes
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 3 then 1
           else 0
           end ) as downvotes
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 2 and t.tagname ='c#' then 1
           else 0
           end ) as [c# up votes]
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 3 and t.tagname ='c#' then 1
           else 0
           end ) as [c# down votes]
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 2 and t.tagname ='java' then 1
           else 0
           end ) as [java up votes]
     , sum(case 
           when v.votetypeid = 3 and t.tagname ='java' then 1
           else 0
           end ) as [java down votes]
from votes v
inner join posttags pt on v.postid = pt.postid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname in ('c#', 'java')
and v.votetypeid in (2, 3)
group by year(v.creationdate)
```

The output of the query can be represented in a Graph like so:

[image: java an c# voting since 2008]

You can find other [starter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239639/what-sede-examples-would-be-most-useful-to-new-users) and [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222544/create-example-reference-queries-on-data-explorer) queries on MSE as well as the [Schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) and an [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439).

There is a ton of specific questions and answers to be found in the [data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag on MSE and there is a tag [data-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) here on MSO as well.